# how to reduce the size of embed Air runtime in Flash pro 6

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

i'm useing a FlashCs6 to create an android apps , there are some users have slow connection or cant use Google play

so i decide to embed Air runtime from publish setting , the problem is when i do this the size of apk is increase about 8 MB !!

and that's not good for and simple application and this 8 MB is problem to download or Bluetooth it and take more time .

is there any way to reduce this Air runtime ?
while I can't use ADT coz some advice me to use...

can you please help me guys , my app size is already large , it's 12MB , so with the embeded runtime it will be 20MB and this is too large >__<

Comment: this is a duplicate of urself
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625238/reduce-size-of-embed-air-runtime-in-flashcs6?rq=1

Comment: even though i didn't got the answer , so may you help !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No can do!
You can't reduce the size of the integrated Runtime.
You can offer both versions. .air for users with AIR installed and a captive version.
Nowadays a 12mb or even a 20mb app shouldnt be a problem.
Depending on what your app actually does, 12mb can be much or not.
Im guessing u can reduce the app size itself (i.e. externalizing assets depending on resolution, ... )

Comment: yes it's not a problem for an app size to be 12 or even 20MB , but in countries where the internet connection is fast, but in my location it's not -unfortunately- ,,,, 
and the app itself is already reduced , it includes a lot of fashion images (online selling) so there are LOTS of images!!!!

anyway MANY THANKS for you , it seems the i'll have to publish it with this large size !

:) thanks again

Comment: your welcome. For online selling the images should be loaded as needed. LazyLoading. Also u can usually reduze Image size drasticly with crunching tools

Comment: I thought about uploading the images , but as i told you , the internet connection is too bad in my country ...
the image size is already 100KB , can it be more reduced and sill shown clear ?!!!
and what crunching tools you suggest that reduce the size and keep the quality ?! IS 100KB still large  ?